# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] but it return a function

Tags: node.js, express

I know the question have been posted several times, and always it's a basic mistake, i already had this issue and always it was a mistake the kind of the already posted question.

It's like the 6th server i make this way, and this time i have no clue why it consider that not being a function.

[here is the error displayed on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebfea.png)

the error occur here

```
const router = require('express').Router();

module.exports = (api) => {

   router.post('/',
       api.middlewares.ensureAuthenticated,
       api.middlewares.bodyParser.json(),
       api.middlewares.agentDispenser.createMyAgent,
       api.actions.hub);

   return router;
}
```

when i comment

```
api.middlewares.agentDispenser.createMyAgent
```

it doesn't crash

my middleware index look like that

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.middlewares = {
        bodyParser: require('body-parser'),
        ensureAuthenticated: require('./ensureAuthenticated'),
        agentDispenser: require('./agentDispenser')
    };
};
```

and agentDispenser look like this

```
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
var agent;

module.exports = (api) => {

    function createMyAgent(req, res, next) {
        agent = new WebhookClient({ req, res })
        return next()
    }

    function getMyAgent() {
        return agent
    }

    return {
        createMyAgent,
        getMyAgent
    }
}
```

as i said, i use the same syntaxe/structure on many project, and it work, so i dont really know what is the probleme, i have read a lot of topic on that, a lot are about a forgoten return or missing (api)... but here i dont know

Thanks for your help in advance

EDIT: shame on me...

Comment: Can you provide also your files naming. in order to know code related to each file

Comment: i got the answer... i wasn't paying enough attention and forgot an (api) despite the fact i usually did like that... Look at Madara Uchiwa answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api.middlewares.agentDispenser.createMyAgent` is `undefined` because `api.middlewares.agentDispenser` is a function that accepts `api` and returns your middleware namespace, and is not the namespace itself.

I'm guessing you want something like

```
module.exports = (api) => {
    api.middlewares = {
        bodyParser: require('body-parser'),
        ensureAuthenticated: require('./ensureAuthenticated'),
        agentDispenser: require('./agentDispenser')(api),
    };
};
```